# ngx-bootstrap tooltip arrow change color with its boundaries of different color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, ngx-bootstrap

[image]

I am using ngx bootstrap tooltip. I am trying to change the color of arrow as:

```
.tooltip.customClass .tooltip-arrow {
    border-right-color: white;
}
```

The issue is that the whole arrow becomes white matching the page background white color and hence becomes invisible. I want to keep the two boundaries of the arrow a different color like say 'black' so I see a white arrow with two black boundaries. I want it to look somewhat like this image attached above:

Answer (score 1):

i'm ngx-bootstrap contributor and there is no easy way to solve this ;)
This arrow actually is a [border](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) and you can't add border to a border.

You can add bigger triangle with needed border-color and hide it under original. For example you can investigate how it's done for ***popover*** arrow in bootstrap.
There are `:before` and `:after` inside `<div class="arrow">`.

```
<div class="popover bs-popover-top bs-popover-top-docs">
    <div class="arrow">
        :before
        :after
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

In this case:

`:before` - bigger triangle with color of arrow border.

`:after` - main triangle with main color.

!But for tooltip component `:before` is a main triangle and if you will add `:after`, don't forget to add `z-index: -1;` for bigger triangle.

And here is [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/zd8by1v5/) for tooltip on the top.

Comment: user2338974, I am still a bit confused. So, if my tooltip uses a containerClass='custom-tooltip', if I add the following in css file, should it work?   .tooltip.custom-tooltip.right .tooltip-arrow:after {
    color:black;
    z-index: -1
}

Comment: Nope, it's not enough. You can add `.customClass` and use it like parent class, but you need to add styles for `:after` pseudo-element, because tooltip doesn't have it by default. 

If you look in my jsfiddle example, css section, there you can find comments `styles for arrow` - this is part you need to add in your case:

1. Main `:after` description
2. Placement fix for `:before`
3. Styles for each placement of tooltip, in my case it's styles for top placement.

Parent or placement classes may be different for bs3 and bs4, like `.top` or `.bs-tooltip-top`

Answer (score -1):

I try this and it works!!!! i can change the arrow color with this:

```
  :host >>> .pending .tooltip-arrow:before,
  :host >>> .tooltip.left .pending .tooltip-arrow::before {
    border-left-color: #eba413 !important;
  }
```

I add it the class pending to have different tooltips depending on the status.